# How to recode multiple columns with the same conditions?

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I have a data set that has over 260 columns that have character values that need to be recoded as numerical factors. For example, `N=0`, `Y=1`, `S=1`, `O=2`, `F=99`. However, apply this to only some columns, not all, so I need to do this by column name. Here is what I have so far:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("N", "N", "O", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "S", "O"),    
                  col2 = c("F", "N", "S", "O", "Y", "Y", "S", "F", "S", "O"),   
                  col3 = c("Y", "O", "Y", "N", "Y", "F", "N", "O", "S", "N"),   
                  col4 = c("S", "S", "O", "O", "Y", "S", "N", "O", "S", "N"),   
                  col5 = c("N", "S", "F", "O", "N", "F", "N", "O", "N", "N"),   
                  col6 = c("O", "N", "S", "N", "N", "N", "N", "F", "N", "O"),   
                  col7 = c("F", "F", "O", "O", "O", "N", "N", "O", "Y", "Y"),   
                  col8 = c("O", "N", "O", "S", "F", "N", "N", "Y", "S", "N"),   
                  col9 = c("N", "O", "O", "Y", "N", "S", "N", "O", "N", "Y"),   
                  col10 = c("N", "N", "S", "F", "N", "N", "F", "Y", "N", "O"))

df %>% mutate_at(.vars = c("col1", "col4", "col9"), funs(ifelse(*** == "N", 0, .)))
```

The 3 astericks indicate the problem. I have to specify the column name to make the recode. I run into the same problem in base R. Is there a way to do it to tell R that "these columns by name when equal to 'N' make 0".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up creating a function with a for-loop, looping through the names of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could do with `across()`.

```
df <- df |> 
  mutate(across(c(col1, col4, col9), ~case_when(.x=="N" ~ 0,
                                         .x %in% c("Y","S") ~ 1,
                                         .x == "O" ~ 2,
                                         .x =="F" ~ 99)))
```

**output**

```
   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10
1     0    F    Y    1    N    O    F    O    0     N
2     0    N    O    1    S    N    F    N    2     N
3     2    S    Y    2    F    S    O    O    2     S
4     0    O    N    2    O    N    O    S    1     F
5     0    Y    Y    1    N    N    O    F    0     N
6     0    Y    F    1    F    N    N    N    1     N
7     0    S    N    0    N    N    N    N    0     F
8     0    F    O    2    O    F    O    Y    2     Y
9     1    S    S    1    N    N    Y    S    0     N
10    2    O    N    0    N    O    Y    N    1     O
```